# I need to load DB configuration dynamically in Drupal 7

Tags: configuration

Can I put `variable_get` in `settings.php` to load DB settings dynamically or there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Database::addconnectionInfo()` to define a new connection at runtime, like this:

```
Database::addConnectionInfo('extradb', 'master', array(
  'database' => 'mydb',
  'username' => 'myname',
  'password' => 'mypass',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
));
```

You can then use `db_set_active('extradb')` to switch to it.

Comment: That code is not tested, by the way, just an example of what I believe should work from reading database.inc.

Comment: The constants in the code can be replaced by variables from variable_get(); You'll need to call this code, which can be placed in a suitable function, before you use the secondary database in your own code.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal allows you to override settings using the $conf[] array in settings.php. They will be then available via variable_get('key', 'default') in any module.

See '[defining site variables'](http://drupal.org/node/1525472) 
and [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)()

The pattern we use is that any defaults go into install.php. starts with:

```
function hottopicsnotify_install() {
  variable_set(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_CONTENT_TYPES_VAR, 'hottopics_node_form');
```

Override the variables with an admin form where needed. e.g.

```
function hottopics_settings($form, &$form_state) {
```

Read using variable_get. e.g.:

```
'#default_value' => variable_get(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_EDITORIAL_CRON_KEY, ''),
```

Comment: I know `variable_get()`, but my question is whether is it possible to use this function in the `settings.php` file or not ?

Comment: No, the settings file is meant to set configuration values. At this point variable_get() is not available. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can only override values in settings. It is for setting. The way to read is variable_get. Are you trying to make a global? How are you planning on using the variable?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I'm trying to make the connection to the DB flexible like the host name of the secondary DB comes from admin settings form ?

Comment: @Interlated I plan to load my secondary DB credential dynamically from admin settings form ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[db_set_active](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7)

You can switch the the active database connection that way.

Define the databases in settings.php, then switch to one with

```
db_set_active('legacy'); // example
// Query stuff using DB API
```

and switch back to default with

```
db_set_active();
```

It's also possible to define the database connection later in code, but hopefully db_set_active will suffice.